# PUR-UnknownExternalError when trying to redeem Microsoft XBOX Gift Cards

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-360

My son bought two US$15 Microsoft XBOX gift cards with his own money (he wants to buy Minecraft). After several hours of unsuccessfully trying to [redeem](https://redeem.microsoft.com/) them on a Windows 10 PC, here we are. It seems we repeatedly receive an error message to this effect:

```
Try that again

Something happened on our end. Waiting a bit might help.

PUR-UnknownExternalError
```

We haven't been able to find anything on the internet that helped. Moreover,

- We have made repeated attempts over a period of several hours.
- Our [AllowMicrosoftAccountSignInAssistant](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/microsoft-store-pur-failure/86cb1d4c-0bda-44cb-90ca-857195f0d5fa?auth=1) was already set to 1.
- The App troubleshooter did not seem to shoot the trouble.
- The trouble started again after a PC restart

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Details may be a little sketchy but... it seems in  the end, it was my wife (my family's resident online shopping expert) who swooped in to save the day with her own idea—first use a credit card to setup a payment plan. After that, my son was able to redeem his gift cards (without making any payments from the credit card). And at last he was able to make the game purchase and happily go about playing Minecraft.

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the card but microsoft site refused the First and Last (despite the fact they were correct). Fortunately the country got registered somehow and I was able to redeem my gift card

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).